# Is there a rotating flash coupler for Canon?

Tags: canon, flash

Is there a flash coupler that can go between the camera body and the flash allowing the flash to rotate side-to-side? Similar to the Nikon AS-1 Flash Coupler.

I want to be as light and versatile as possible, and therefore use one of the smaller speedlights, but they only rotate up. Yes, I can use my 580ex or transmitters, but that becomes more clunky and overkill than a small, versatile flash.

Comment: I don't believe that there is, but I could be wrong. What use would you gain from it? Strobes have pivot heads and radio transmitters don't need to be pointed in a direction...what accessory are you using that would benefit from this? (just curious)

Comment: I want to be as light and versatile as possible, and therefore use one of the smaller speedlights, but they only rotate up. Yes, I can use my 580ex or transmitters, but that becomes more clunky and overkill than a small, versatile flash.

Comment: Gotcha - so a flash bracket would definitely be out as well...

Comment: Got one of those already ;)

Comment: I'm also assuming simply using the AS-1 and manual flash settings isn't an option...?

Comment: @scheduledForDeletion, the AS-1 was an adapter for Nikon bodies that didn't have standard flash hotshoes. It doesn't use a standard flash foot on the bottom. See http://www.mir.com.my/rb/photography/hardwares/coupler/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you'll find one, as these days, most speedlights have heads that swivel. I'd suggest that you consider trading in a little bulk for swivel capability, and looking at purchasing a Canon-compatible small hotshoe flash with a swivel head, such as a [Canon 320EX](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/products/details/cameras/flashes/speedlite-320ex) (270º), [Godox TT350](http://www.godox.com/EN/Products_Mini_Camera_Flash_TT350C.html) (270º), [Nissin i40](http://www.nissindigital.com/i40.html) (360º), or [Meike MK320](https://www.lightingrumours.com/meike-mk320p-review-7458) (150º).